# Twitter digits api Authorization using curl

Tags: curl, oauth, authorization, twitter-digits

I did the exact same request as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409536/twitter-digits-api-authorization) but I didn't had an extra quote and I still get the same error :/ Is there something else I'm missing?

```
curl --get 'https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature="<signature>",oauth_nonce="6E3DCF1C-BAE4-41CE-B7EF-7314A3358273",oauth_timestamp="1480777938",oauth_consumer_key="<consumer_key>",oauth_token="<token>",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"' --verbose
```

Comment: It works for me. I receive "Invalid or expired token".

Comment: @ganzogo It's because you have to replace `<token>` by your own. Same goes with `<consume_key>` and `<signrature>`. If you to so, you should have `{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}` as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `oauth_signature` value wasn't encoded, doing so seems to fix the issue.